# Save column list for re-use in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of tables in my database with common columns like these first three:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `created_date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ...other columns specific to the table
```

Is it possible to save writing down this subset of columns so that my sql can look something like this:

```
common_columns = [
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `created_date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
]

CREATE TABLE person (
    common_columns,
    ...other columns specific to the table
```

I know you can reuse SQL expressions, but I couldn't find anything about this type of thing.

Another idea I thought of would be to save

```
create_base = CREATE TABLE @table_name (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `created_date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

And immediately after `ALTER` the table to add the columns specific to the table, but I'm unsure if I can save that query for reuse either.

Comment: You can do it in a stored procedure that constructs the SQL dynamically and uses `PREPARE`.

Comment: There's no way to do it in ordinary SQL.